# Search operation within array of objects?

Tags: c++, class

I am making simple bank program,My class name is bank

it consist of following functions `deposit()`, `withdraw()`, `show()`, `getname()`, `getbalance()`, default constructor and parametric constructor.

I'm trying to do a search operation in the main program by name and by balance.
BUT,Instead of showing the info of the corresponding name or balance entered,it's showing the entire list of info of account holders.

Please Help to rectify this problem.

---

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>

class bank
{
   char name[20],acNo[20],typeOfAc[10];
   double balance;
   public:
   bank()
   {
      strcpy(name,"NULL");
      strcpy(acNo,"XXXX");
      strcpy(typeOfAc,"XXXX");
      balance=0;
   }
   bank(char nm[20],char acn[20],char tac[10])
   {
      strcpy(name,nm);
      strcpy(acNo,acn);
      strcpy(typeOfAc,tac);
      balance=0;
   }

   double getbalance(){return balance;}
   char* getname(){return name;}
   void enter();
   void deposit();
   void withdraw();
   void show();
};

void bank::deposit()
{
   double d;
   cout<<"\nEnter Amount To deposit:";
   cin>>d;
   cout<<"\n";
   balance=balance+d;
   cout<<"\nSuccessful Deposit.\n";
}
void bank::withdraw()
{
   double w;
   cout<<"\nEnter amount to withdraw:";
   cin>>w;
   cout<<"\n";
   if((balance-w)<0)
   {
      cout<<"\nCan't withdraw!!";
      cout<<"\nYour Balance:"<<getbalance();
      return;
   }
   else
      balance=balance-w;
   cout<<"\nWithdrawal Successful.\n";
}
void bank::show()
{
   cout<<"\nName:"<<getname();
   cout<<"\nBalance:"<<getbalance();
}
void bank::enter()
{
   cout<<"\nPlease enter the following info\n";
   fflush(stdin);
   cout<<"\nName:";
   gets(name);
   cout<<"\n";
   cout<<"\nACcount Number:";
   gets(acNo);
   cout<<"\n";
   cout<<"\nType of Account:";
   gets(typeOfAc);
   cout<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   double b1;
   char n[20],nn[20];
   bank b[10];
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      b[i].enter();
      b[i].deposit();
   }
   //search by name
   cout<<"\nEnter the name for search by name:";
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(n);
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      strcpy(nn,b[i].getname());
      if(strcmp(nn,n)==0);
      b[i].show();
   }
   cout<<"\nEnter the balance for search by balance:";
   cin>>b1;
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      if(b[i].getbalance()==b1);
      b[i].show();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I would also suggest you use `std::string` instead of c-strings.

Comment: `if(strcmp(nn,n)==0);` ends the if clause. The following line will be executed regardless of what the conditional evaluates to. Remove the `;` from that line. The same error is repeated in   `if(b[i].getbalance()==b1);`

Answer (score 4):

```
if(strcmp(nn,n)==0);
b[i].show();
```

and

```
if(b[i].getbalance()==b1);
b[i].show();
```

It's the `;` on the first line of each...  that turns it into an empty if condition.  The second line is unrelated to the `if` and is always run.  This is one of the reasons you should always use curly braces for every `if` statement, even if it's only one line.

Comment: Oh, just now saw r sehu's comment with the same answer..

Comment: It's better to close such questions with "simple typographical error" reason. Such questions and any answers to those are not useful to the general SO audience.

Answer (score 2):

You have terribly mixed-up C and C++. I would've done a pure C++ class declaration, like this

```
class bank {
    string name, acNo, typeOfAc;
    double balance;
public:
    bank(string nm = "NULL", string acn = "XXXX", string tac = "XXXX")
        : name(nm), acNo(acn), typeOfAc(tac), balance(0) {}

    double getbalance() { return balance; }
    string getname() { return name; }
    . . .
};
```

Here, `string` is `std::string`.

Instead of

```
char n[20];
fflush(stdin);
gets(n);    // unsafe
```

should be

```
string n;
cin >> n;
```

and, to correct your search

```
if (b[i].getname() == n)    // no semicolon here
    b[i].show();
```